# Icons of default folder are gone

Tags: release-loki, icons, folder

Default icons of default folders in file manager are gone even though I am using default theme and icons. (checkout image below)

[image: elementary os loki default folder icons missing]

Please  help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution from reddit.

Make sure the contents of `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```